# How to rollback changes in android studio?

Tags: java, android, xml

By mistake I have updated my older files. Is there any way to rollback those transactions. I have executed the update statement from management studio and the script does not have in Begin Trans/rollback/commit.

Comment: Do you use some Version control system?

Comment: How much changes have you made?

Comment: I am still lost, are you looking to rollback from database perspective or you are referring to IDE files code changes reversal?

Answer (score 9):

In Android studio click to folder that you updated by mistake and open:
VCS-> Local History -> Show History

[image]

It will open list of changes by time, that was done by you locally. Move to time before you made mistake, and right click on it and click Revent. 
[image]